# How to show a jagged array in Unity3d inspector?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, jagged-arrays

I want to make a jagged array to order a group of waypoint systems. My problem is that I don't know how to show the jagged array in the Unity inspector so that I can fill the different arrays with the game objects I want (basically, squares of a board game).

The game is a board game with different paths the players can choose from (e.g Mario Party). In order to do so, instead of making a typical lineal waypoint system (from A to B) I thought about making several waypoint systems so the players can 'jump' from one waypoint system to another when they arrive to an intersection. As I wrote, I don't know how to show the jagged array in the inspector so that I can work properly. I tried to put [system.serializable] over the script class, but it doesn't work, the arrays simply don't appear.

```
public Transform[][] waypointSystems = new Transform[][] 
    {
      new Transform[1],
      new Transform[43],
      new Transform[1],
      new Transform[5],
      new Transform[7]
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer: You can't that simple. Muktidimesnional and jagged arrays are not serialized.

One way could be to wrap one dimension of the array in another class like

```c#
[Serializable]
public class TransformArray
{
    public Transform[] Array;

    public TransformArray(Transform[] array)
    {
        Array = array;
    }
}

public TransformArray[] waypointSystems = new TransformArray[]
{
    new TransformArray(new Transform[1]),
    new TransformArray(new Transform[43]),
    new TransformArray(new Transform[1]),
    new TransformArray(new Transform[5]),
    new TransformArray(new Transform[7])
};
```

---

Alternatively you can write a [`[CustomEditor]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) but that there it gets really complex. You might be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49482716/7111561)

or try to implement your own inspector usig the code snippet from [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/231715/is-there-any-way-to-view-2d-arrays-in-the-inspecto.html) as a Startpoint

```c#
SerializedProperty data = property.FindPropertyRelative("rows");
for (int x = 0; x < data.arraySize; x++) 
{
   // do stuff for each member in the array
   EditorGUI.PropertyField(newPosition, data.GetArrayElementAtIndex(x), GUIContent.none);
}
```

Comment: The first way works like a charm, but I'm gonna read about the other options. Thank you for the help!